# Asynchronous loading Google Maps and dependent scripts in Rails/Coffeescript/jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to load Google Map after clicking the button/link, to limit the number of requests to Google Maps API (costs!*). What makes it a bit more complicated than a simple 'script' element injection (append) onclick event is the fact that I also need to load 2 more libraries in the same way: marker_with_label and infobox, wrapped in one file 'extra_libs.js.coffee'. They can only be loaded once google maps api is fetched. Also, running other scripts has to wait until these two libs are fetched.

I have a working solution, but I'm not sure if defining and then triggering $(window).load is the right way to go. Please review, maybe you guys know better ways to do this? I was thinking about setting timeouts, deferring execution until 'jQuery.active' == 0 etc. but I couldn't find as simple and short solution as the one below:

```
# Callback function used when google map api is loaded, must be a global function
window.load_scripts = ->
  $('<%= javascript_include_tag asset_path('extra_libs'), id: :extra_libs %>').appendTo('body') unless $('#extra_libs').length
  $(window).load ->
    init_map_and_street_view()
  $(window).trigger('load') # it doesn't work if we don't trigger this manually

# do some stuff with the map, init, set center etc.
init_map_and_street_view = ->
  App.gMap.init('blablabla')
  App.gMap.getMap().setCenter(App.gMap.getLocation($('#map')))
  #...

load_map = ->
  $('<%= javascript_include_tag map_url+"&callback=load_scripts", id: :google_maps_api %>').appendTo('body') unless $('#google_maps_api').length

$('#tab_map, #tab_street').click =>
  load_map()
```

- what counts is how often you load google maps api in a 'script'

'''UPDATE'''
As per @Archer 's suggestion, I changed $(window).load to $.getScript (== $.ajax) and simplified things a bit and also seems faster:

```
window.load_scripts = ->
  $.getScript('<%= asset_path("extra_libs") %>', init_map_and_street_view)
```

The rest remains the same

Comment: I'm in the middle of something so can't put together a proper bit of code for an answer, but have a look at jQuery's `getScript()`.  It has a callback parameter that may solve your problem... http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: Thanks! It's actually a shorthand to common $.ajax, it seems that it does the job for loading additional, gmaps dependent libs asynchronously:

    window.load_scripts = ->
      $.getScript('<%= asset_path("extra_libs") %>', init_map_and_street_view)